# mysql_fetch_array skipping first row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using this same process to create and populate tables - Everything works fine except that the **first row is skipped in every table**. Could use another pair of eyes as I can't seem to pinpoint the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM members";
   $results = mysql_query($query);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

   
   //echo my <table> start and headings;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Last Name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['First Name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Middle Name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Sfx']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Prf']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Spouse/SO']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Ancestor']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Status']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Address 1']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Address 2']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['City']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['ST']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Zip 5']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Zip 4']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Home Phone']."</td>";
    echo '<td><a href="mywebsite/mypage.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Bio</a></td></tr>';
    }

    echo "</table><hr>";
```

Comment: You're calling `mysql_fetch_array` twice, hence the reason.  Remove the first call.

Comment: what @vinodadhikary said, your problem is line 3. If the commented code in line 6 needs it then change your loop to `do { } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))`

Comment: Ditto with John Conde and Chad. You should also use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead because mysql_fetch_array() pretty much doubles up on the amount of data that PHP is manipulating.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are calling mysql_fetch_array twice... once before the loop then once while looping.

If you need a seed row for use in building your header row you might be better served with a do.. while loop here.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);

//echo my <table> start and headings;

do  
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Last Name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['First Name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Middle Name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Sfx']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Prf']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Spouse/SO']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Ancestor']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Status']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Address 1']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Address 2']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['City']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['ST']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Zip 5']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Zip 4']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Home Phone']."</td>";
    echo '<td><a href="mywebsite/mypage.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Bio</a></td></tr>';
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results));

echo "</table><hr>";
```

Comment: Nice one! Awesome suggestion with the `do...while`. But this might just confuse the OP!  Some explanation on how `do...while` works and why the OP's code is not generating expected result would make it more awesome!

Comment: I'm quite familiar with the do...while - just needed some direction as I've been getting a little burnt out and these little things slip by me! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results); <-- There's your first row. Remove this.
```

Comment: This is because the first call sets the array pointer to the first element, and then the second call -in while loop- set the pointer to the second element.

Answer (score 2):

There is extra `mysql_fetch_array` in the code. Also, opening table tag(`<table>`) is missing.

Corrected code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members";
$results = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row['Last Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['First Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Middle Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Sfx']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Prf']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Spouse/SO']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Ancestor']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Status']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Address 1']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Address 2']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['City']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['ST']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Zip 5']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Zip 4']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Home Phone']."</td>";
echo '<td><a href="mywebsite/mypage.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Bio</a></td></tr>';
}

echo "</table><hr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You call mysql_fetch_array when you initialize $row, which reads the first row. You then call it a second time when you begin your while loop, which moves it to the second row before any of your loop is ran. Hence, it never does anything with the first row.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row) 
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row['Last Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['First Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Middle Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Sfx']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Prf']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Spouse/SO']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Ancestor']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Status']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Address 1']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Address 2']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['City']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['ST']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Zip 5']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Zip 4']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Home Phone']."</td>";
echo '<td><a href="mywebsite/mypage.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Bio</a></td></tr>';
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

}

echo "</table><hr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, just comment out the 3rd line `$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);`
The query will fetch every single row after that.